# Boot Linux in Normal World

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot, bare-metal, trustzone

I am exploring the **TrustZone** (the ARM security extension) on an **i.MX53** Quick Starting Board. I succeeded to make a bare-metal system : A secure world image and a normal world image. I load the two images in my ram with **u-boot** and I boot the secure world **who initializes the monitor system** and gives the hand to the normal world image.

I want to use the same system. But this time instead of using a normal world basic image, I would like to use a **Linux Kernel Image**. I did some configurations that I found in the i.MX53 Reference Manual and the i.MX53 Security Reference Manual when I am in the secure world. The configurations are :

- Configure the CSU : `CSL0-31 to 0x00FF_00FF`
- Configure the TZIC (interrupts) `TZIC_INTSEC0-3 to 0xFFFF_FFFF`, `TZIC_PRIORITY0-31 to 0x1F1F_1F1F` and `TZIC_INTCTRL to 0x8001_0001`
- Configure Secure Configuration Register : `NS=0 IRQ=0 FIQ=0 EA=0 FW=1 AW=1 => 0x30`

When I give the hand to the linux kernel, the boot process starts, here is a part of the output :

> regulator: core version 0.5
>
> NET: Registered protocol family 16
>
> i.MX IRAM pool: 128 KB@0xec840000
>
> **FAILED TO RELEASE IRAM PARTITION**
>
> CPU is i.MX0 Revision 0.0
>
> **Unhandled fault: external abort on non-linefetch (0x1008) at 0xec82c00c**
>
> Internal error: : 1008 [#1] PREEMPT
>
> last sysfs file:
>
> Modules linked in:
>
> CPU: 0    Not tainted  (2.6.35.3 #1)
>
> PC is at mxc_cpu_lp_set+0x1c/0x16c
>
> LR is at arch_idle+0x60/0x294
>
> pc : [<8003a958>]    lr : [<8003ab08>]    psr: 60000093
>
> sp : 80835f78  ip : 00000003  fp : 8088fb68
>
> ....

As you can notice in the output, there is a problem with the **IRAM** (because normally it diplays IRAM READY) and there is a data abort. After so displays related to these errors, the Linux kernel boot process stops.

Any ideas of how to solve that ? Am I missing any configuration ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this post](https://community.freescale.com/thread/308152) on the *Freescale* forum?

It seems to be the exact same problem you're having. Basically, it is probably trying to access a register, at `0xec82c00c` virtual address, which is configured by default to be **non-accessible** from the *Normal world*.